# How do I add a MIME type to .htaccess?

Tags: java, apache, .htaccess, mime, jnlp

I would like to add the following MIME type to a site run by `Apache`:

```
<mime-mapping>
  <extension>jnlp</extension>
  <mime-type>application/x-java-jnlp-file</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

**That is the Tomcat format.**

I'm on a shared host, so I can only create an `.htaccess` file. Would someone please specify the complete contents of such a file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
AddType application/x-java-jnlp-file .jnlp
```

Note that you might not actually be allowed to do that.

See also the [documentation of the AddType directive](http://HTTPd.Apache.Org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype) and the [.htaccess howto](http://HTTPd.Apache.Org/docs/trunk/howto/htaccess.html).

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to just add this line:

```
AddType application/x-java-jnlp-file     .jnlp
```