# rewrite mod htaccess all folders

Tags: css, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to route all folders and subfolders to my index document.
It is working, but not completely, when I go deeper into a subfolder, the index.shtml getting loaded but without any CSS.

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
    RewriteRule (.*) index.shtml [L]   
</ifModule>
```

*domain.tld/folder-1/folder-2* (any deeper then folder-1 and the CSS is gone.)

Comment: Found that the file paths of my css must reflect the path in the url, absolute paths or hit back to root.

Comment: I wanted just to suggest you the same solution.

Comment: The problem is now that all my js/css/images files are being transferred as text/html. How can I prevent that going to happen?

Comment: @barry http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33751/how-do-i-add-a-mime-type-to-htaccess